# @Factory annotation does not execute testng classes as desired

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, testng

For my current project i am using `testng` classes and `@factory` to call them. Following are the code

`test1`

```
    public class Test1 extends Setup{
      @Test
      public void facebook() {
          System.out.println("Inside Facebook");
      }

      @BeforeClass
      public void beforeClass() {
          driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
      }

      @AfterClass
      public void afterClass() {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
      }
}
```

`test2`

```
public class Test2 extends Setup{
  @Test
  public void google() {
      System.out.println("Inside Google");
  }

  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass() {
      driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
      driver.close();
      driver.quit();
  }
```

`setup`

```
public class Setup {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public Setup(){
        initialise();
    }

    public void initialise()
    {
//      SELECT THE CUSTOM PROFILE FOR SKIPPING THE TRUST CERTIFICATE
        ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni();               
        FirefoxProfile ffProfile= prof.getProfile("MyProfile");

//      ADDING THE PAGE ON EXCETION
        ffProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        ffProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

//      INVOKE THE DRIVER
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
    }
```

`Factory Class`

```
public class Driver {
    @Factory
    public Object[] objInitialise(){
        ArrayList<Object> module = new ArrayList<Object>();
        module.add(new Test1());
        module.add(new Test2());
        return module.toArray();
    }
```

now after running `driver` class, first it opens one browser having url: `about:blank&utm_content=firstrun`, and later opens another browser with desired url: `https://www.facebook.com/`.

In eclipse console, i see the below error

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'

Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:377)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
    at TestMavenGroupId.TestMavenArtifactId.Test2.beforeClass(Test2.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Following should be the actual output that i am looking for

```
Inside Facebook
Inside Google
```

can you please help me understand what is that I am missing. I am not getting the right output. I want separate browsers to open for each test and launch the url one after the other on respective browsers.

Selenium Version: 2.53.1
Firefox Version: 47.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, i had to initialize the driver in the respective test class and avoid using `driver.quit()`, this is because the `driver` was  declared `static`. now following is the test codes

```
    public class Test1 extends Setup{
      @Test
      public void facebook() {
          System.out.println("Inside Facebook");
      }

      @BeforeClass
      public void beforeClass() {
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
      }

      @AfterClass
      public void afterClass() {
            driver.close();
      }
   }
```